# Losing file extension when uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-extension

I am using Amazon S3 to store images and I want my app to upload an image here. My code looks like this:

```
private void imageRetrieved(String selectedImagePath){
    File f = new File(selectedImagePath);
    new uploadImage().execute(f);
}
```

Where selectedImagePath equals "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picture.jpg". My problem is, that this code DOES upload the picture but without extension, so in the bucket there is a file "picture", but I want it to be "picture.jpg". Any idea how to fix this?

```
private class uploadImage extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(File... params) {
        PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, IMAGE_NAME, params[0]);  
        s3c.putObject(por);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `IMAGE_NAME` "picture" or "picture.jpg"?

Comment: :D oh god thank you im really tired. (yes it was "picture" and should be "picture.jpg")

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the full file name, "picture.jpg" in your case, in the 2nd parameter of the constructor of `PutObjectRequest`.